# Invalid Json Primitives

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, javascriptserializer

Could you help me for resolving this issue. I have one asp.net application, in this i am using Javascript serializer for serializing a dataset followed by convertion to the list. That code is shown below.

```
JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
strJson = json.Serialize(aclDoc);
```

But, at the time of deserializing i got one ArguementException like Invalid Json Primitives with my Json value. My json value is

```
[{"Id":"F79BA508-F208-4C37-9904-DBB1DEDE67DB","App_Id":"ScriptFlow","Name":"New form","FriendlyName":"","Read":"Revoke","ReadRule":"a353776f-cbdc-48b7-a15b-4a2316d19b05","Update":"Grant","UpdateRule":"be30c34e-33ec-4c0a-9f09-4fd483f5f1b9","Create":"Revoke","CreateRule":"898dce4d-4709-45b6-8942-d7efb07cbd86","Delete":"Revoke","DeleteRule":"aa14d435-dec8-4ade-ad9b-830ae5ee15d0"}][{"Id":"1","Doc_Id":"858E013C-5775-4FDF-AA1E-2C84053EE39F","Name":"TextBox1","FriendlyName":"TextBox1","Read":"Grant","ReadRule":"0a2e3c0e-ad8f-4f75-9160-cfd9827ac894","Update":"Grant","UpdateRule":"ecad3cf4-104f-44dc-b815-de039f3a0396"},{"Id":"2","Doc_Id":"858E013C-5775-4FDF-AA1E-2C84053EE39F","Name":"TextBox2","FriendlyName":"TextBox2","Read":"Grant","ReadRule":"81e0e9ef-09f7-4c25-a58e-d5fdfbd4c2ba","Update":"Grant","UpdateRule":"2047f662-c881-413b-a1f9-69f15bf667fc"}]
```

The code for deserializing is:

```
JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
lstDoc = json.Deserialize<List<ACLDocument>>(value);
return lstDoc;
```

where lstDoc is a List Collection of type of my class

I got the exception like this:

```
Invalid JSON primitive:
{"Id":"1","Doc_Id":"858E013C-5775-4FDF-AA1E-2C84053EE39F","Name":"TextBox1","FriendlyName":"TextBox1","Read":"Grant","ReadRule":"0a2e3c0e-ad8f-4f75-9160-cfd9827ac894","Update":"Grant","UpdateRule":"ecad3cf4-104f-44dc-b815-de039f3a0396"},{"Id":"2","Doc_Id":"858E013C-5775-4FDF-AA1E-2C84053EE39F","Name":"TextBox2","FriendlyName":"TextBox2","Read":"Grant","ReadRule":"81e0e9ef-09f7-4c25-a58e-d5fdfbd4c2ba","Update":"Grant","UpdateRule":"2047f662-c881-413b-a1f9-69f15bf667fc"}].
```

Please help me for resolving this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input string is really a **wrong** JSON string. You input consist from two correct JSON strings:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "F79BA508-F208-4C37-9904-DBB1DEDE67DB",
        "App_Id": "ScriptFlow",
        "Name": "New form",
        "FriendlyName": "",
        "Read": "Revoke",
        "ReadRule": "a353776f-cbdc-48b7-a15b-4a2316d19b05",
        "Update": "Grant",
        "UpdateRule": "be30c34e-33ec-4c0a-9f09-4fd483f5f1b9",
        "Create": "Revoke",
        "CreateRule": "898dce4d-4709-45b6-8942-d7efb07cbd86",
        "Delete": "Revoke",
        "DeleteRule": "aa14d435-dec8-4ade-ad9b-830ae5ee15d0"
    }
]
```

and

```
[
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Doc_Id": "858E013C-5775-4FDF-AA1E-2C84053EE39F",
        "Name": "TextBox1",
        "FriendlyName": "TextBox1",
        "Read": "Grant",
        "ReadRule": "0a2e3c0e-ad8f-4f75-9160-cfd9827ac894",
        "Update": "Grant",
        "UpdateRule": "ecad3cf4-104f-44dc-b815-de039f3a0396"
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Doc_Id": "858E013C-5775-4FDF-AA1E-2C84053EE39F",
        "Name": "TextBox2",
        "FriendlyName": "TextBox2",
        "Read": "Grant",
        "ReadRule": "81e0e9ef-09f7-4c25-a58e-d5fdfbd4c2ba",
        "Update": "Grant",
        "UpdateRule": "2047f662-c881-413b-a1f9-69f15bf667fc"
    }
]
```

but you **can not concatenate** two JSON strings. To say exactly what you receive after such concatenating in not more a JSON string.

I recommend you to verify JSON strings in http://www.jsonlint.com/. Just cut and paste the data which you need to verify and click "Validate" button.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question directly, since everyone thinks this is a Microsoft forum and not answering directly.

The string is sent as a 2 element array. You forgot the '[' in the beginning of the string which denotes that the containing values are an array structure.

Insert the '[' in the beginning of the string and the error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

This is a useful little tool for examining your JSON objects:

http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

See if you have any // or commented lines in project.json
Removing this has solved the same problem for me